# How to plot a Circles-and-Squares fractal

Tags: plotting, generative-art, fractals

The Circles-and-Squares fractal is produced by iteration of the equation

$\quad \quad  z_{n+1}=z_n^2\ ({\rm mod}\; m)$

which results in a Moiré-like pattern:

[image: CirclesandSquares]

Source: [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circles-and-SquaresFractal.html)

In another place I found the same pattern, but the equation said ${\rm modulo}\  n$ instead of $m$. Either way, this equation is very similar to the one generating the Mandelbrot set. How can it be plotted?

Comment: No doubt there are more concise ways but try `With[{r = Range[-50, 50]^2}, Image@Rescale@Mod[Outer[Plus, r, r], 100]]`

Comment: In this way we get a low-res picture that's not scalable. The result should be plot or other similar constructs that are vectorial and can be exported as such (like in *.svg).

Comment: @BoC. you can double the numbers and change `Image` to `ArrayPlot` in Simon's code to get a plot and higher resolution. E.g. `With[{r = Range[-100, 100]^2}, 
 ArrayPlot@(1 - Rescale@Mod[Outer[Plus, r, r], 200])]`

Comment: You should state your requirements in the question. I doubt you'll get a vectorial representation of a fractal image, though, unless it is something procedurally generated (e.g.  by an L-System or such).

Answer (score 16):

The image taken from MathWorld appears to be something like this:

```
Image @ Rescale @ Table[Mod[x^2 + y^2, 100], {x, -50, 50}, {y, -50, 50}]
```

[image]

In my opinion this is not a fractal, and it certainly isn't produced by iteration. You described it as "Moiré-like", which is a far better description. It is simply a uniformly sampled 2D parabola, modulo some number. The pattern arises from the interaction between the fixed frequency of the sampling and the increasing frequency of the underlying function.

It's clearer in 1D:

```
Plot[Mod[x^2, 100], {x, -50, 50}, Exclusions -> None, PlotPoints -> 200, 
 PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5], AspectRatio -> 0.3, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[Medium], Point[{#, Mod[#^2, 100]} & /@ Range[-50, 50]]}]
```

[image]

So I don't really understand your comment about it being low-res and wanting a vectorial representation. The pattern appears **because** of the finite spatial sampling. Zooming into the function is very boring - you will just see the underlying wrapped parabola, not the never ending detail that a fractal provides:

[image]

### Something prettier

Ignoring the picture in the question, and looking at the iteration $z_{n+1}=z_n^2\ ({\rm mod}\; m)$ gives something much nicer (in my opinion). Here it is with $m=2$ and 1 to 4 iterations:

```
z0 = Table[x + I y, {x, -3.001, 3, 0.01}, {y, -3.002, 3, 0.01}];
results = Rest @ NestList[Mod[#^2, 2] &, z0, 4];   
GraphicsGrid[Partition[Image @ Rescale @ Abs @ # & /@ results, 2]]
```

[image]

Comment: *That's* an answer.  (Crocodile Dundee voice)

Comment: That is something prettier.  1970s version: `WatershedComponents[Image@Rescale@Abs@results[[4]]] // Colorize` (better if resolution is doubled).

Comment: @MichaelE2, love it! Try this one: `{b,h}=Rescale@#@results[[3]]&/@{Abs,Arg};
Image[{h,1-0b,1-b},Interleaving->False,ColorSpace->"HSB"]`

Comment: How about only one set of concentric circles? Which part of the equation defines the ratios of successive circles' radius?

Comment: @SimonWoods Oh that hurts my eyes!

Comment: @BoC., sorry I don't quite understand what you're asking. You would have to do some analysis to see why the circles are the sizes they are.